# Tree. What is the location of the generated text file?

Tags: files, terminal, tree

Ubuntu. Tree.

```
tree -fi /path/to/the/directory >~/file.txt
```

I see the files in terminal but was under the impression that a text file called 'file.txt' would be generated, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

It is in your home directory. The one which you are in right after the login.

The symbol `~` (tilda) is a shortcut for it. Another way to define home directory is `$HOME`. Or you can specify an absolute path, which would be `/home/username`

Comment: (It's "tilde" but pronounced with a strong "d" as if it's "tilda".)